Conditionals for future in the past usage
I was wondering what is the correct usage of expressing conditions while storytelling.
Let's assume that the story is told by the main character as if it were a journal. The narrator says that he was at odds with his colleague at the time, but he was considering a scenario which could help them make up.
This could be an excerpt from his story:

That day I finally made up my mind. If I stopped distracting her from work, maybe she would appreciate it.

Is the second conditional correct in this sentence? After all it is claimed that it refers to hypothetical present and future situations. Here, in fact, we refer to the future, but in the past. Is it still applicable, though?

It's perfectly fine.

This is an example of narrative retrospection with internal monologue. The person is writing down what they thought at the time. The conditional has likely since been put to the test, and what the narrator writes next may indicate how that went. But the sentence in question is fine and quite common in linear story-telling.
